# How do I update a model object's associated object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I want to something like the following:

```
@user.update_attributes(:name => "Obama", :profile => { :current_location => 'US' })
```

where User has_one profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make them 'nested attributes'. [The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) says:

Consider a Member model that has one Avatar:

```
  class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :avatar
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
  end
```

...

allows you to update the avatar through the member:

```
  params = { :member' => { :avatar_attributes => { :id => '2', :icon => 'sad' } } }
  member.update_attributes params['member']
  member.avatar.icon # => 'sad'
```

Answer (score 1):

As bjelli has stated it's the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method that you probably want here. It's important to notice that it is the passing in of the profile's :id attribute that allows it to recognize it's an update you want to peform.

I would recommend reading this the [nested_attributes.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d32965399ccfa2052a4d52b70db1bae0ca16830b/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb) comments to understand more : )